# JavaScript An array with two numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I want an array and each array I want to numbers in that array, like

`test[1]` would output `[2,1]` or whatever.

I KNOW I can do just shove two numbers with a delimeter like `"|"` and it would output `"2|1"` but I wanted to know if there was an official way of adding two separate numbers in one array element...

Comment: So, you want a value that can hold multiple other values, like a list or so. Mmmmmh.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arrays as values too:

```
var test = [[4,3], [2,1]];
console.log(test[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert an array as an element of another array.

Example:

```
var dimensions = [];

dimensions[0] = [1,2];
dimensions[1] = [3,4];
```